# How to backup sybase database with date/time stamp

Tags: database, backup, sybase

How to backup sybase database with date/time stamp using command line?

Saw somebody posted this method:

`declare @pvm varchar(30), @dumptorun varchar(300), @dbname varchar(70)
select @pvm=(CONVERT(varchar(30), GETDATE(), 112))
select @dbname='master'
select @dumptorun = 'dump database '+@dbname+' to d:\temp\'+@dbname+'_'+@pvm+'.dmp'
select @dumptorun
EXEC ( @dumptorun )`

Tried it and removed the go, but still stuck with some errors, it complains some syntax errors with "/"

Anybody can help? Thanks.

Comment: please post the output of `select @dumptorun` as well as the complete error message; is this Sybase ASE?

Comment: This is what I've used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @pvm varchar(30), @dumptorun varchar(300), @dbname varchar(70)
select @pvm=(CONVERT(varchar(30), GETDATE(), 112))
select @dbname='master'
select @dumptorun = "dump database " + @dbname + " to '/backup/DB/"+ @dbname+"_"+ @pvm + ".dmp'"
select @dumptorun
EXEC ( @dumptorun )
```

This works on Unix - you would need to adjust for windows as your original question has a windows directory but your answer seems to imply a unix directory type instead so would need the slashes and drive etc to be changed.

The key is that you need quotes around the backup file name so I just changed your concatenated strings to double quotes so that its easier to add the single quote you need.

Comment: How to add date & time stamp with this? I tried using this statement, but it did not work. 

`select @pvm=(CONVERT(varchar(30), GETDATE(), 112)) + (CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 24))`

Desired output:
20181110.195010
(yyyymmdd.hhmmss)

Comment: The standard ASE date formats are here - http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1570/html/blocks/X41864.htm
The 24 format is not valid which is why yours didnt work. You could use select (CONVERT(varchar(30), GETDATE(), 112)) + '.' + (CONVERT(varchar(30), GETDATE(), 108)) but this will give you colons between your time settings. If you specifically don't want the colons then you'll have to use the datepart function instead to get the parts of the date but then 08:00 would get 8 for the hour part rather than 08.

Comment: Ah yes just removing them with str_replace is way easier than datepart good call :)

Answer (score 0):

`declare @pvm varchar(30), @dumptorun varchar(300), @dbname varchar(70)
select @pvm=(CONVERT(varchar(30), GETDATE(), 112))
select @dbname='TOB'
select @dumptorun = 'dump database '+@dbname+' to /backup/DB/'+@dbname+'_'+@pvm+'.dmp'
select @dumptorun
EXEC ( @dumptorun )
go`

`Msg 102, Level 15, State 181:
Server 'SOL', Line 1:
Incorrect syntax near '/'.`